# Join two files ordered numerically according to second column

Tags: awk, sort, join

I have two files

file 1 contains

```
2*J=0 EXP= 0.00000
2*J=4 EXP= 1.27911
2*J=8 EXP= 1.57613
2*J=12 EXP= 1.69134
2*J=10 EXP= 2.72705
2*J=16 EXP= 4.55689
2*J=20 EXP= 5.62138
```

file 2 contains

```
2*J=0 EXC= 0.00000
2*J=8 EXC= 1.21836
2*J=4 EXC= 1.59642
2*J=12 EXC= 1.78359
2*J=10 EXC= 2.69484
2*J=16 EXC= 7.24518
2*J=20 EXC= 7.32688
```

I want to join the two files such that the output will be

```
2*J=0 EXP= 0.00000 EXC= 0.00000
2*J=4 EXP= 1.27911 EXC= 1.59642
2*J=8 EXP= 1.57613 EXC= 1.21836
2*J=12 EXP= 1.69134 EXC= 1.78359
2*J=10 EXP= 2.72705 EXC= 2.69484
2*J=16 EXP= 4.55689 EXC= 7.24518
2*J=20 EXP= 5.62138 EXC= 7.32688
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with GNU awk, we can control how the output is sorted:

joiner.awk

```c
#!/usr/bin/env -S gawk -f

FILENAME == ARGV[1] {
    f1[$1] = $2 OFS $3
    sort_key[$1] = $3
    next
}

{
    f2[$1] = $2 OFS $3
}

function sorter(idx1, val1, idx2, val2) {
    return sort_key[idx1] - sort_key[idx2]
}

END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "sorter"
    for (key in f1)
        print key, f1[key], f2[key]
}
```

Then

```bsh
$ gawk -f joiner.awk file1 file2
2*J=0 EXP= 0.00000 EXC= 0.00000
2*J=4 EXP= 1.27911 EXC= 1.59642
2*J=8 EXP= 1.57613 EXC= 1.21836
2*J=12 EXP= 1.69134 EXC= 1.78359
2*J=10 EXP= 2.72705 EXC= 2.69484
2*J=16 EXP= 4.55689 EXC= 7.24518
2*J=20 EXP= 5.62138 EXC= 7.32688
```

The "PROCINFO" magic is documented: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Array-Traversal.html

Comment: AWK is universal. Using `printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n", key, f1[key], f2[key]` yields well formatted output.

Comment: GNU awk is not universal however.

Answer (score 1):

For `join`, the inputs have to be sorted lexically on the joining key. If you need the result to be sorted some other way, you have to do that sorting after joining:

```
$ join <(sort -bk1,1 file1) <(sort -bk1,1 file2) | sort -k3n
2*J=0 EXP= 0.00000 EXC= 0.00000
2*J=4 EXP= 1.27911 EXC= 1.59642
2*J=8 EXP= 1.57613 EXC= 1.21836
2*J=12 EXP= 1.69134 EXC= 1.78359
2*J=10 EXP= 2.72705 EXC= 2.69484
2*J=16 EXP= 4.55689 EXC= 7.24518
2*J=20 EXP= 5.62138 EXC= 7.32688
```

`sort -k3n` sorts numerically on the part of the line that starts with the third field (by default, fields are delimited by transitions from non-blank to blank, so that sorting key includes leading blanks and what's after the number, but both are ignore upon interpreting that as a number; a more correct way to specify the third blank delimited field would be `sort -bk3,3n`, where `-b` strips the blanks and `3,3` picks *only* the third field; in practice here, that makes no functional difference).

Process substitution (`<(...)`) is a Korn shell extension. It's also available in the `zsh` and `bash` shells.

`sort -bk1,1` sorts lexically on the first blank-separated field (the key `join` joins on by default).